# Convert Text to Canvas Image, Preserving Formatting

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I'm building a chrome extension that needs to convert text to image, preserving the formatting. Looks like this will be possible using the result from window.getSelection, but it also is going to be a bit of a slog to program all of the edge cases. Been looking for an existing solution on the nets but haven't seen one - is anyone aware of the existence of such tech?

If not, I'll post my work to github when it's further along :)

Cheers,

Allan

Answer (score 0):

**Canvas itself can directly draw simply formatted text.**

[image]

These properties can be used to affect how text is drawn on a canvas

- **font**: size & fontface
- **textAlign** (horizontal alignment): start, end, left, right, center
- **textBaseline** (vertical alignment): alphabetic, top, hanging, middle, ideographic, bottom
- **strokeStyle** (color outlining the glyph): rgba, hex, webcolor name, a gradient
- **fillStyle** (color filling the glyph): rgba, hex, webcolor name, a gradient
- **Opacity**: set on 0.00 (fully transparent) to 1.00 (fully opaque) scale
- **lineWidth** (thickness of the outlining stroke): 0.50+
- **transformations** (scale & rotate the text)
- **clipping**: text can be clipped by defined paths
- **compositing** (interaction of text and other drawings):

And you can use `context.measureText` to get the width of text

You can convert text drawn on the canvas to an image using `canvasElement.toDataURL`

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.font='60px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.fillStyle='green';
ctx.lineWidth=2;

ctx.translate(100,50);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/16);
ctx.fillText("Earth",0,0);
ctx.strokeText("Earth",0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

ctx.translate(275,50);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/16);
ctx.fillText("quake",0,0);
ctx.strokeText("quake",0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

var textAsImage=new Image();
textAsImage.onload=function(){
  document.body.appendChild(textAsImage);
}
textAsImage.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<p>Simple text drawn on a canvas element</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=150></canvas>
<p>The canvas converted to an image</p>
```